# Sencha touch list with index bar : auto scroll

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm starting in sencha touch ,and I try to create an application.only,I have a problem. I use a list with indexbar. this list is in a panel. and I wonder if it's possible to add an event listener to the panel, to jump to an index to the next. Let me explain with an example:

-We have a list of products and these products are sorted by their type (phones,computers...), the indexbar lets you know what type of product it is.

-To switch from one type to another,We Have to scroll.

What I seek to do is put a listener to the panel so that the scroll from one type to another is automatic every time you tap on the panel or on a next button. for example.

Please excuse my english and help

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dom property scrollTop .

For example:

```
el.dom.scrollTop =  1000;//this will push the panel down by 1000px;
```

You can always get the el, dom from panel/element properties/ attributes list.